# Let $(X, Y)$ be a random vector, consider

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X, Y)$ be a random vector, consider

$$f(x, y)=c \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) ^{x+y}, x=0, 1, 2, y=1, 2$$

Find the value of the constant $c$ that makes the function $f(x, y)$ a density function and determine whether the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
Calculate the probabilities $P(X=1)$, $P(X=2|Y=2)$, $P(XY=2)$

Contribution:

[image]

[image]

To say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent I have to verify it for $x=0, 1, 2$, $y=1, 2$?

Comment: Does the problem specify possible values for $x$ and $y$? For example, could $y$ be 5?

Comment: $x=0,1,2,y=1,2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Based on the supports of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, we must have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x\in\text{supp}X}\sum_{y\in\text{supp}Y}p_{X,Y}(x,y) & = c\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0+1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0+2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1+1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1+2} +\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2+1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2+2}\right]\\\\
& = c\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}\right) = 1
\end{align*}

In order to determine the marginal probability mass functions, you can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
p_{X}(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{y\in\text{supp}Y}p_{X,Y}(x,y)\\\\
p_{Y}(y) = \displaystyle\sum_{x\in\text{supp}X}p_{X,Y}(x,y)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Finally, once you have the value of $c$ and the marginal distributions, you can verify if $X$ and $Y$ are independent (does $p_{X,Y} = p_{X}p_{Y}$ hold always?) as well as determine the corresponding probabilities of interest.

Comment: To verify that they are independent, you should verify for all $x=0, 1, 2, y=1, 2$

Comment: That's the point. You should compare the values $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ with $p_{X}(x)p_{Y}(y)$ for every possible entries.

Comment: Ok. I have done so, and I can say that X and Y are independent.